# Alternate diff tool not firing from gitk for Windows

Tags: git, gitk

I have git cli and gitk working fine.

I use Beyond Compare as a diff tool, and configured git via the steps I found [here](https://www.chadly.net/git-bcompare/).

I can see that these commands kicked in here:
[image]

But when I use the "Diff" options shown in this menu, nothing external fires. Gitk just operates as always.

[image]

I found this in Preferences, and set it to the beyond compare binary, but also no change in behavior.

[image]

I always fully exited Git GUI after making these changes. But the diff behavior never changes.

How do I get Beyond Compare firing?

Comment: GItk's support for using `git difftool` appears to be missing. It should work fine from command-line Git, but not from `gitk`. (Note that `gitk` and `git-gui` are different programs. `git-gui` may or may not support difftool usage; I did not check. However, git-gui appears to be considered a useless toy by the Git folks. Gitk is supported outside the core Git team, which is the only way it ever gets any attention either....)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is... use a different git gui....

I tried a couple. Landed on Sourcetree, which easily allows Beyond Compare to be triggered, and supports the standard ctrl+D hot key to fire a diff.

I still don't understand why these guis don't allow me to multi select any two commits and do a diff via external diff tool. (Perforce is just sooooo much better... git is just so loosely structured it makes me crazy.)

Answer (score 0):

Right click a file path in the bottom right view. Choose `External diff`.

This will open the currently selected diff, which is shown in the bottom left view, in your configured diff tool.

The option `Diff this -> selected` changes the selected diff, but does not automatically open it in a separate program.